# XSLT - styling a changing/variable element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some documents that look like this:

```
<p>It is a <noun>truth</noun> <adverb>universally</adverb
<verb>acknowledged<verb>, that a <adjective>single</adjective>
<noun>man</noun> in <noun>possession<noun> of a 
<adjective>good</adjective> <noun>fortune</noun>, 
<verb>must</verb> <verb>be</verb> in want of a <noun>wife</noun>.</p>
```

(Except hundreds of pages long and with many more element names)

I want to use XSLT to output html files, each of which shows every paragraph that contains a particular element and highlights that element. So the paragraph above might end up in every output file, but in one the verbs would be highlighted and in another the nouns would be highlighted. It wouldn't show up at all in the "conjunctions" file because it doesn't contain that element.

For named elements I've been using this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">      
        <xsl:result-document method="html" href="nouns.html">
            <html>
                <body>
                    <xsl:for-each select="collection('index.xml')//p[.//noun]">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        </p>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="noun">
    <span class="highlight">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

(In this scenario there are other templates that match on other elements to style italics/superscripts etc)

This works perfectly, but I need a way to automate producing separate documents for a very long list of elements. I have a separate document that lists these elements and their associations:

```
<speechParts>
  <speechPart><name>Nouns</name><tagName>noun</tagName></speechPart>
  <speechPart><name>Verbs</name><tagName>verb</tagName></speechPart>
  ...
</speechParts>
```

I've tried generating all the files I need by applying the following style-sheet to the list above:

```
<xsl:template match="/">   
  <xsl:for-each select="speechParts/speechPart">
        <xsl:result-document method="html" href="{name}.html">
            <html>
                <body>
                    <xsl:for-each select="collection('index.xml')
                       //p[.//*[name()=current()/elName]]">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        </p>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[name()=current()/elName]">
    <span class="highlight">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

This doesn't work because the template doesn't know what the current value of 'elName' is, I guess. I played around for ages with variables but I don't think XSLT will let me use a variable or a parameter as a match pattern.

It seems like this should not be as complicated as I'm making it...

(This is a follow on question from a question I asked yesterday. Thank you so much for helping me - it's really helping me to learn.)

Comment: There is something unreasonable in your request: you are creating HTML documents and copying elements that make no sense within an HTML document, such as <adjective>.

Comment: I know it's a bit messy, but such is the XML I'm working with. I figured it'd be easiest to make sure the tags that need to be turned into spans worked first, and then I could strip out all the noise in the resultant html later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you try it along these lines:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="speechParts/speechPart">
        <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="tagName"/>
        <xsl:result-document method="html" href="{name}.html">
            <html>
                <body>
                    <xsl:for-each select="collection('index.xml')//p[.//*[name()=$elemName]]">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:apply-templates>
                                <xsl:with-param name="elemName" select="$elemName" tunnel="yes"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </p>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="elemName" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name()=$elemName">
            <span class="highlight">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is utterly perfect. It does exactly what I need. Thank you so very much. (My text book didn't include the concept of tunnels, and this is an excellent thing to learn about.)